# Ant, set environmental variable for <ant> task?

Tags: ant, environment-variables, environment, task

I want to run another ant build file from ant, and the `<ant>` task looks perfect for this.

The other build file uses environmental variables for a couple things.  Is there a way to set environmental variables for the child ant process?

I see that the `<exec>` task seems to support nested `<env>`s, but nothing similar for `<ant>`.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html),

By default, all of the properties of the current project will be available 
in the new project.

You can also set properties in the new project from the old project by using 
nested `property` tags.

```
<ant antfile="subproject/property_based_subbuild.xml">
  <property environment="env"/>
</ant>
```

Comment: It's my understanding that `<property environment="env"/>` simply loads the current environmental variables into an ant property called "env", no?  So this might be OK if the other build file uses the same `<property environment="env"/>` line, and only uses these environment variables through `${env}`, but it won't actually set any environmental variables in the child ant process.  (I'll give it a shot when I get to work, though.)

Comment: I don't see the point of your suggestion in this context - Ken's existing script would have to refer to env vars with a leading `"env."` for it to work.  And if it does that, it will already be running `property environment="env"` itself.

Answer (score 0):

by default the inner ant call inherits the parent properties

```
<ant inheritAll="true" antfile="subproject/subbuild.xml">
  <!--inheritAll="true" is default value, this is unecessary -->

  <property name="myprop" value="foo"/>

  <antcall target="myTarget"></antcall> 
  <ant antfile="myAntFile"></ant>

</ant>
```

In this case, "myTarget" and all targets on "myAntFile" can get "foo" as "myprop" value.